# Rotating pulsars about maximum moment of inertia

Tags: rotational-dynamics, astrophysics, moment-of-inertia, pulsars

Pulsars rotate very fast.
Its axis of rotation may be or may not be aligned with the axis of the radiation beam.

But, you see with respect to the Dzhanibekov effect, the pulsar should be rotating with its maximum moment of inertia.the Dzhanibekov effect states that  The spinning body ends up in the spin state that minimizes the kinetic rotational energy for a fixed angular momentum (this being the maximal-inertia axis).

Now take a snapshot of the pulsar at a time (say $T$).

consider a radiation beam as having some mass. we have considered continuous radiation beam as having some mass(mass in shape of cylindrical rod). As radiation also emits (electron-positron), one can consider radiation as a rod of mass.

Now imagine two rods in opposite direction are attached to the neutron star (two rods are basically radiation emitted in opposite direction ).then  maximum moment of inertia will lie on the axis perpendicular with respect to the axis of radiation line.

the above written conditions are my Imagination.

so lets bring Dzhanibekov effect here!
the body should rotate on axis perpendicular to the axis of radiation (or axis perpendicular to rod).

Take a pulsar. suppose, its radiation is along **z** axis, it should rotate about either X or Y axis , to maximize its moment of inertia. But the Pulsars can be tilted  at any angle? Why?
we do have pulsar having rotational axis tilted not necessarily 90 degrees with respect to beam.

why Dzhanibekov effect is not followed?
Where I am getting wrong?

The NASA satellite **Explorer 1**, was also crashed due to this phenomenon.